# Method does not override any method from its superclass , Alamofire

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode, alamofire

I am trying to create a XCFramework from Alamofire source code . 
I was able to create frameworks for iOS and iOS-Simulator, I tested both frameworks in a test code worked fine. 
I added this to XCFramework , it was successful , added the XCFramework to rest code but now I receive following error

```
Method does not override any method from its superclass
```

Above error is for method `cleanup()` , I think the swift interface generated has some issue.

I created the frameworks using following commands

```
xcodebuild archive -workspace Alamofire.xcworkspace -scheme "Alamofire iOS" -sdk iphoneos OBJROOT=build/iOS
xcodebuild archive -workspace Alamofire.xcworkspace -scheme "Alamofire iOS" -sdk iphonesimulator OBJROOT=build/simulator  
xcodebuild -create-xcframework -framework ios_fr/Alamofire.framework -framework ios_sim_fr/Alamofire.framework -output build/Alamofire.xcframework
```

Everything goes well but it failed in loading framework with above error.

Any help in this direction is appreciated .

Comment: Why don't you share the overriding and the overriden class definitions. It's hard to help you unless you can post some code.

Comment: @Rob thanks for reply , its standard Alamofire framework I didn't update anything and error is for only one method I have mentioned it already

Answer (score 0):

I am facing the same problem. So i reviewed the code that causes this problem:

```swift
// Superclass "Request"
func cleanup() 

// problem area: Child Class "UploadRequest"
public func cleanup()
```

`internal` (default) has been override as `public` i think this is a mistake.

Make `Request`'s instance  method `cleanup` to `public` to fix this.